# How can I SUM up all prices according to its sales_order_id (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, sum, sql-order-by

I am retrieving **sales records** with its **product/s ordered**. I want to **add or sum all** of the **product_price** according to its order_id

My current query looks like this:
[image]

**Problem:** When I put a **SUM( bsb.PRICE )**, **MySql is combining** all the product prices.
[image]

This is the query that i used:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id, bsd.PRICE AS shipping_total, SUM(bsb.PRICE) AS product_price, '' AS order_total
FROM b_sale_basket bsb
INNER JOIN b_sale_order bso ON bso.ID = bsb. ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
INNER JOIN b_sale_pay_system bsps ON bso.PAY_SYSTEM_ID = bsps.ID
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (255, 300)

) sales_order
```

**Note:** The output I desire is to sum all product_price **according to its order_id**. So the **final output should have 2 rows** not 1 row

Please help me...

Comment: you're missing your `GROUP BY` clause - you need to tell MySQL how you want to group your aggregated data!

Comment: Just add a group by `group by bsb.ORDER_ID`

Comment: just as a note when you use an aggregate function aka COUNT() SUM() MAX() MIN()... etc. lets just use SUM() since you are.. SUM is telling mysql to take all rows and "sum" them together on a specific column. if you don't add a GROUP BY.. then it will combine all rows... the GROUP BY tells mysql that you want to SUM data specific to another column aka your orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify, how the compiler should treat all the columns, which are not used in a aggregation function, i.e., not one of `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `COUNT`. In your case you have to say the compiler, that you want "for each ... the sum of ...", so `GROUP BY bsb.order_id`.

```
SELECT bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id, SUM(bsb.PRICE) AS product_price, '' AS order_total
FROM b_sale_basket bsb
INNER JOIN b_sale_order bso ON bso.ID = bsb. ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
INNER JOIN b_sale_pay_system bsps ON bso.PAY_SYSTEM_ID = bsps.ID
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (255, 300)
GROUP BY bsb.ORDER_ID
```

Comment: try and provide some explanation rather than just a solution

Comment: and the OP doesn't need this as a sub query so you should remove that as well

Answer (score 1):

Then just use group by on the order id, this will tell MySQL how you want to aggregate your values:

```
SELECT 
  bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id, 
  bsd.PRICE AS shipping_total, 
  SUM(bsb.PRICE) AS product_price, 
  '' AS order_total
FROM b_sale_basket bsb
INNER JOIN b_sale_order bso ON bso.ID = bsb. ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
INNER JOIN b_sale_pay_system bsps ON bso.PAY_SYSTEM_ID = bsps.ID
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (255, 300)
GROUP BY bsb.ORDER_ID
```